# How to get all the streets and their postal codes from a given state (New Hampshire) that has been loaded inside PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I downloaded .osm for state New Hampshire from [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/new-hampshire.html). I loaded it into PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 16.04 VB using `osm2pgsql`. When I use `\dt` on my db it shows this:

[image]

However `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM county;` returns 0. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planet_osm_point;` returns 55083.

I'd like to get a list of all towns and all streets in those towns. However, there are no counties, nevermind towns!

Also `\d+ planet_osm_point` shows this;

[image]

Then I tried `SELECT amenity FROM planet_osm_point LIMIT 10` and it just returns empty space with 10 rows:

[image]

**EDIT**:

Managed to get towns, cities, counties, types of `highway`. But can't get streets for a given city.

Answer (score 3):

To future readers who might struggle with the same problem, here are the queries that have helped me:

#### How to get all the streets and their postal codes from a given state (New Hampshire) that has been loaded inside PostgreSQL:

#### 1. To get the list of all counties in NH:

`SELECT name FROM planet_osm_point WHERE place='county';`

returns 10 rows, which is correct as NH has 10 counties.

#### 2. To get a list of all cities:

`SELECT name FROM planet_osm_point where place='city';`

returns 13 rows which is correct as [NH has 221 towns and 13 cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_New_Hampshire)

#### 3. To get a list of all towns:

`SELECT name FROM planet_osm_point where place='town';`

returns 45 which is not correct, since we need 221 town.

#### 4. To get a list of all possible values for `place`:

`SELECT DISTINCT place  FROM planet_osm_point;`

[image]

returns 17 rows with unique values. The remaining towns must be somewhere among those other place tags.

#### 5. Then I put all the cities and towns (234 in total) from Wikipedia into a `.txt` file and got all the rows where `name` is inside that `.txt` file of mine (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884906/4759176):

**The number of unique cities/towns that are in my Wikipedia's list**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(*) FROM planet_osm_point 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM citiestowns 
WHERE citiestowns.name=planet_osm_point.name)>0 AND place is not null;
```

returned `count=236`. So there must be 2 extra rows (not sure how it's possible, though).

**The table with names and places of those cities**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  name, place FROM planet_osm_point 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM citiestowns 
WHERE citiestowns.name=planet_osm_point.name)>0 AND place is not null order by name asc;
```

[image]

returns a list that looks same as the one from Wikipedia.

**All possible values of `place` in the previous table**:

```
SELECT place, COUNT(place) FROM planet_osm_point 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM citiestowns 
WHERE citiestowns.name=planet_osm_point.name)>0 
AND place is not null GROUP BY place ORDER BY count DESC ;
```

returned

[image]

so, OSM tagged most of the remaining towns as villages. Btw, what in OSM was tagged is neighbourhood is a `Populated places` in Wikipedia's table.

#### 6. Getting streets for retrieved towns/cities. Still not sure how to do it

**all possible values for `highway`**:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT highway FROM planet_osm_line;
```

[image]

```
SELECT area, highway FROM planet_osm_line where highway is not null and area='Acworth';
```

returns zero rows

#### 7. Getting postal codes of all the streets in 234 cities/towns.

Answer (score 1):

`osm2pgsql` will not create/update/touch/know anything about the tables from the `tiger` schema. They must come from somewhere else.

For the `planet_osm_point` query, don't forget to filter results. While all points are saved in this table, not all of them are an `amenity`

```
SELECT amenity 
FROM planet_osm_point 
WHERE amenity  IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Good point! I managed to get 10 amenities that way. However, how would I get all the towns and their streets in New Hampshire then? I thought that downloaded .osm file would be enough. I tried `SELECT area FROM planet_osm_point WHERE area IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10` but it returned 0

Comment: OSM tables are "put it all" containers. You should look at which OSM **tags** you need, and query the tables on these tags

Comment: I managed to get towns and cities, however I still struggle with roads. Selecting the towns `WHERE highway IS NOT NULL` returned null. So when it's my town, highway is empty. I tried to `SELECT area, highway FROM planet_osm_line where highway is not null and area='Acworth'; ` to get highways in Acworth city, but it returns 0 rows.